# Replacing the Month Number with the Month Name from a Query()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am grouping data by month in a Google Sheets QUERY using the MONTH function. However, it returns the month number from 0-11 and I prefer to see the month names.

Here is the QUERY

```
=QUERY(DataAllMonths!A1:B, "SELECT MONTH(A), COUNT(A) WHERE LOWER(B) LIKE '%no empathy%' GROUP BY MONTH(A) LABEL MONTH(A) 'Month', COUNT(A) 'Total'", True)
```

This returns something like the following:

[image]

I ended up writing a customer function to take the results from the QUERY and substitute the month names for the numbers

```
=returnMonthName(QUERY(DataAllMonths!A1:B, "SELECT MONTH(A), COUNT(A) WHERE LOWER(B) LIKE '%no empathy%' GROUP BY MONTH(A) LABEL MONTH(A) '', COUNT(A) ''", True), 1)
```

And this shows the following result

[image]

Here is the script

```
function returnMonthName(data, col) {
  // var data = [[1, 100], [2, 200], [3, 300]];
  // var col = 1;
  var months = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
  var retArray = [["Month","Total"]];
  var total = 0;
  // var retArray = [];
  var n = 0;
  var dataLen = data.length;
  for (n = 0; n < dataLen; n++) {
    retArray.push([months[data[n][0]], data[n][1]]);
    total+= data[n][1];
  }
  retArray.push(["Total", total]);

  return retArray;
}
```

I believe there is a way to do this without depending on a custom function, perhaps using an array formula. Does anybody have a solution.

[Here is a link to a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/136CQyRTVXmB3DbfGLc2pK6CfixYEO1Lx83jOSQ8t1Co/edit#gid=1794629727).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By formula only, Try

```
=QUERY({arrayformula(eomonth(DataAllMonths!A1:A,0)),DataAllMonths!B1:B}, "SELECT (Col1), COUNT(Col1) WHERE LOWER(Col2) LIKE '%no empathy%' GROUP BY (Col1) LABEL (Col1) 'Month', COUNT(Col1) 'Total'", True)
```

[image]

and change format of column to MMM

[image]

### reference

[EOMONTH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093044)

Comment: Thank you Mike, that was exactly what I was looking for and I believe I now understand how to feed QUERY() massaged data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function lfuncko(m) {
  return [...Array.from(Array(12).keys(), x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2022, x, 15), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM"))][m]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a custom function working. I was looking for a solution that uses native google sheet functions if possible.

Comment: So you're looking for a formula, not Apps Script?

Comment: @Coper, interesting! if month is 1,2,3,... then you would have [m-1] in the script

Comment: Try running it.  You will find that it works, Tthe months range from 0 - 11